# SQL order of function explanation for trim, replace and left trim

Tags: sql, netezza

Good day,

I found a very useful piece of code in Netezza SQL that removes leading zeroes from ID numbers. I however don't fully understand the logical processing in SQL behind it. Could someone please assist in explaining how SQL goes about processing the line of code below? I understand that one reads from the inside out but the section between the LTRIM and the second replace statement confuses me.

SUBSTR(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(TRIM(ID_NO),'0',' ')),' ','0'), 1, 13)

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LTRIM` works with whitespace. So this code

a) Removes any surrounding whitespace (`TRIM`)

b) Replaces 0s with whitespace (inner `REPLACE`),

c) `LTRIM`s the string (which will only remove leading whitespace, which must have originally been 0s because of (a))

d) Replaces the whitepaaces back to 0s (outer `REPLACE`)

e) (not really relevant here) then does a `SUBSTRING` to the result.

The overall effect is, *for those 0s at the start of the string*, they're removed. All other 0s are not affected (whilst pretending to be spaces) by the `LTRIM`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use convert function. As you know that only numbers are coming in input.

```
declare @tst as Varchar(50)='   001256'

select   Convert(int,@tst)
```

**Output :** 1256